# Update Parent via Child components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to update state of the parent component `App.tsx` via child component `RemarksView.tsx`. Tried passing props i.e., `setRemarks` and `remarks` But for some reason the state in parent component is not updating.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean const `const [Remarks, setRemarks] = useState(Form.remarks)` ?|

Also you try to equal `if (id == e.target.id)` but `e.target.id` equal to `"1"` and id is equal to `{id: "1", text:"hello man"}`. inputDetails consist of objects from remarks array, but it don't consist if ids

Yu should change `inputDetails?.map((id:number, index:number) => {` to `inputDetails?.map(({ id }, index:number) => {`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-raman-m423hf?file=/src/App.tsx I tired but its not working. I am unable to update the parent object ```Form```

Comment: Because setRemarks has array as an argument, and you provide object. And in sandbox you don't fix my comment about changing inputDetails?.map((id:number, index:number) => {